# Pyinstaller creates Trojan Virus when converting files

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, virus, trojan

I had a perfectly normal file. I downloaded pyinstaller, created a .exe with it, and wanted to share it. I uploaded it to dropbox, filehopper and one more (cant remember which) each time i tried to share it. Every single time, when i download the file to check if it works, my computer says trojan virus detected and quarantines the file. How do I fix/whats wrong??? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem has recurrence in Pyinstaller version 6.0 as of Sep 2023. Windows defender detects virus in File pywin32-ctypes module. Pyinstaller itself reports that the file pywin32-ctypes module infected with a virus or Potentially unwanted program.
Current Solution: Uninstall pywin32-ctypes and Pyinstaller 6.0

> pip uninstall pywin32-ctypes pyinstaller

downgrade Python to version 11.1(dont know if this was necessary) and downgraded Pyinstaller to version 5.5

> pip install pyinstaller==5.5

Answer (score -2):

This is not trouble with python or .exe - this is antivirus policy. If you want to distribute your app/program you need certificate. Or you can tell your clients to disable AV (very bad solution - your reputation and trust may be trashed). Best way is to redistribute python programs is as-is with .py or (if there is need for compiling) in source format - let the clients do rest of work - open source. If you need closed source app - you buy certificate.

Comment: What is client has no python reader or wants to download reader?